# How to tell IntelliJ get FXML controller from FXMLLoader for syntax hilighting?

Tags: javafx, fxml, fxmlloader

My JavaFX project follows these steps: 
 Compute optimal values in `Model` class
 initialize `Controller`
 create a new instance of `FXMLLoader`
 set `Controller` and `view.fxml`
 render View

My fxml file doesn't have a line like `fx:controller="com.example.Controller"`. IntelliJ fails to resolve methods like `onMouseClicked="#processMyButtonClick"` because it doesn't know what controller to use. `No Controller specified for top level element`. Is there a way to tell IntelliJ. If controller is specified in FXML Java throws `Controller value already specified` exception.

As a result source control logs are polluted with false positives "100 errors were found" and a link between `#methodName` in `fxml` and `public void methodName(){/*..*/}` stops working.

Is there a way to tell IntelliJ to derive fxml  controller from POJO class?

---

Based on ["No Controller specified for top level element" when programatically setting a Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32868089/no-controller-specified-for-top-level-element-when-programatically-setting-a-c)
one can specify controller in fxml file, but this is undesirable because I would like to initialize Controller before fxml is loaded.

Comment: Probably not what you want, but it's possible to both specify `fx:controller` and initialize the controller before initialize the controller before anything is injected to it by using a `controllerFactory`.

Comment: Why don't you want to include controller inside of the FXML file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I also hated this for a long time, but I have found a work around. You specify the Controller in the FXML file and then load it like this:

```
public static Node loadScene(Controller c) {
    URL resource = Controller.class.getResource("/scene.fxml");
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(resource);
    loader.setControllerFactory(param -> c);
    loader.load();
    return loader.getRoot();
}
```

Comment: Minimally invasive procedure. Thanks.