# JavaFX and CDI: How to Inject many Stages

Tags: javafx-8, cdi

I would like to integrate JavaFX and CDI. There are some good examples over the web about that like these ones:

https://dzone.com/articles/fxml-javafx-powered-cdi-jboss
http://fxapps.blogspot.com.br/2017/10/using-cdi-20-in-javafx-application.html

However, all the examples I have seen don't work in a real world because they are not able to inject more than one Stage (the primaryStage), if they are, I don't know how.

So I would like to know if it's possible in a JavaFX/CDI project to inject more than one Stage (to use in modal windows for example...)

thank's!

Comment: Seems strange to inject a stage into anything - neither of the links you provided use the DI framework to manage the stage. I can't see any reason that any component would have a dependency on a stage. Usually you use dependency injection frameworks in JavaFX to inject models and services into the controllers, and establish other dependencies among the models and services.

Comment: James_D, thank's for replying! The problem is that to show modal dialogs I need a new Stage for them, thus, the question is how could I get that Stage? If I call **new Stage()** the CDI beans won't get injected into the controller of that Stage.

Comment: Just create a new stage. Why do you need the DI framework to create it?

Comment: *"If I call `new Stage()` the CDI beans won't get injected into the controller of that Stage."*. This doesn't make sense. Controllers are not created when you call `new Stage()`, they are (typically) created when you load the FXML file. Just instruct the `FXMLLoader` to create controllers via CDI in the usual way.

Comment: "_they are (typically) created when you load the FXML file_" yes! So how could I inject any CDI bean (such as services for example) into this controller - IF - its FXML represents a modal window with its own Stage?

Comment: *"how could I inject any CDI bean (such as services for example) into this controller"* The same way as it's done in the first link in your question. There is absolutely nothing specific to the `primaryStage` in the way the `FXMLLoader` is used there.

Comment: I tried that way, but the CDI beans won't get injected, i.e., they remain null! I guess that's because a modal window requires a new stage for it...

Comment: Your guess is probably wrong. It's much more likely that you just have an error in your code. Again, a controller cares nothing about which stage the UI it is controlling is displayed in.

Comment: ok, thanks, James! I will check my code up. I will be back with the code if couldn't figure out what's wrong

Comment: Posted an answer, containing a complete example which has multiple stages and uses CDI to share a model between two controllers. You should be able to copy, paste, and run this under JDK 1.8.0 and weld-se 2.4.5.

Answer (score 8):

You don't need to use CDI to manage the stages: stages themselves simply have a `Scene`; they do not have any dependencies on any other objects you need to manage. All you need to do is ensure that the `FXMLLoader` has a `controllerFactory` that retrieves controller instances from the DI framework.

Here is a quick example (caveat: I have never used CDI/Weld before, so I might not have the optimal way of doing things here).

First, it's probably a good idea to expose a controller factory that gets the appropriate controllers:

```
package app;

import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Instance;
import javax.inject.Inject;

import javafx.util.Callback;

@ApplicationScoped
public class CDIControllerFactory implements Callback<Class<?>, Object> {

    @Inject
    private Instance<Object> instance ;

    @Override
    public Object call(Class<?> type) {
        Object controller = instance.select(type).get();
        return controller;
    }

}
```

Here is a model class we want to share with all the controllers. Since we only want one instance, we make it `@ApplicationScoped`:

```
package app;

import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;

@ApplicationScoped
public class Model {

    private final ObservableList<String> names = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    public ObservableList<String> getNames() {
        return names ;
    }

    public void addName(String name) {
        names.add(name);
    }
}
```

The test application will just have a list view (with a list of names) and a button for adding a new name from a dialog. Here is the main controller:

```
package app;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.inject.Inject;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MainController {

    @Inject 
    private Model model ;
    @Inject 
    private CDIControllerFactory controllerFactory ;

    @FXML
    private ListView<String> listView ;

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        listView.setItems(model.getNames());
    }

    @FXML
    private void showAddDialog() throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(AddNameController.class.getResource("AddNameDialog.fxml"));
        loader.setControllerFactory(controllerFactory);
        Scene scene = new Scene(loader.load());
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Note how it uses the controller factory on the `FXMLLoader`. The stage can just be created "by hand".

Here's the controller for the dialog that is used to add new names. Note how it has a reference to the same model instance, via CDI:

```
package app;

import javax.enterprise.inject.Default;
import javax.inject.Inject;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

@Default
public class AddNameController {

    @Inject
    private Model model ;

    @FXML
    private TextField nameField  ;

    @FXML
    private void submit() {
        model.addName(nameField.getText());
        close();
    }

    @FXML
    private void close() {
        nameField.getScene().getWindow().hide();
    }
}
```

Here are the two FXML files (they are both in the `app` package: the only real requirement with the way I coded these is that they should be in the same package as their corresponding controller classes).

Main.fxml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ListView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>

<BorderPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="app.MainController">
    <center>
        <ListView fx:id="listView" />
    </center>
    <bottom>
        <HBox alignment="CENTER">
            <padding>
                <Insets top="5" right="5" left="5" bottom="5" />
            </padding>
            <Button text="Add..." onAction="#showAddDialog" />
        </HBox>
    </bottom>
</BorderPane>
```

AddNameDialog.fxml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ListView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>

<BorderPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="app.MainController">
    <center>
        <ListView fx:id="listView" />
    </center>
    <bottom>
        <HBox alignment="CENTER">
            <padding>
                <Insets top="5" right="5" left="5" bottom="5" />
            </padding>
            <Button text="Add..." onAction="#showAddDialog" />
        </HBox>
    </bottom>
</BorderPane>
```

Here's the application class:

```
package app;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.jboss.weld.environment.se.Weld;
import org.jboss.weld.environment.se.WeldContainer;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    private Weld weld ;
    private WeldContainer container ;

    @Override
    public void init() {
        weld = new Weld();
        container = weld.initialize();
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        weld.shutdown();
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(MainController.class.getResource("Main.fxml"));
        loader.setControllerFactory(container.select(CDIControllerFactory.class).get());
        Scene scene = new Scene(loader.load(), 600, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

and of course the CDI configuration class, `META-INF/beans.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
        xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
                      http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
        bean-discovery-mode="all">
</beans>
```

---

If you really want to let CDI provide your stages, you can, but I don't really see there's much to gain by it. But, e.g. you can do something like:

```
package app;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import javax.inject.Qualifier;

@Qualifier
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD,
        ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.PARAMETER})
public @interface ModalStage { }
```

which lets you provide modal and non-modal stages:

```
package app;

import javax.enterprise.inject.Produces;

import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class StageProducer {

    @Produces
    public Stage stage() {
        return new Stage();
    }

    @Produces
    @ModalStage
    public Stage modalStage() {
        Stage stage = stage();
        stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        return stage ;
    }
}
```

And then your `MainController` might look like

```
public class MainController {

    @Inject 
    private Model model ;
    @Inject 
    private CDIControllerFactory controllerFactory ;

    @Inject
    @ModalStage
    private Stage addNameDialogStage ;

    @FXML
    private ListView<String> listView ;

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        listView.setItems(model.getNames());
    }

    @FXML
    private void showAddDialog() throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(AddNameController.class.getResource("AddNameDialog.fxml"));
        loader.setControllerFactory(controllerFactory);
        Scene scene = new Scene(loader.load());
        addNameDialogStage.setScene(scene);
        addNameDialogStage.show();
    }
}
```

There are other facilities you could easily build into this, e.g. providing a class for loading FXML from a resource name, which incorporates the controller factory already, etc etc.