# Second window in Fxml

Tags: java, fxml

it's me again. Now i have another problem with my program. I try to open new window(stage) by button buy it doesnt work. I don't know what i must to do :( I know it's easy problem but i don't see it and i need your help .

ControlPane

```
package source;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ControlPanel {
    @FXML
    Button button;
    @FXML
    PasswordField passField;
    @FXML
    TextField loginPanel;
    @FXML
    Button btnOpenNewWindow;
    public void show(){
        System.out.println("Work");
    }
    @FXML
    public void log (){
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String login =loginPanel.getText();
        String login1 = "ala";
        String pass = passField.getText();
//        String pass1 = "1234";
        if(login.equals(login1)&& pass.equals("123")){
            System.out.println("zalogowales sie");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Nie zalogowales sie ");
        }
    }

        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            try {
                FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("source/menuPane.fxml"));
                Parent root1 = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load();
                Stage stage = new Stage();
                stage.setTitle("My New Stage Title");
                stage.setScene(new Scene(root1, 450, 450));
                stage.show();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

First fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField?>
<FlowPane prefHeight="334.0" prefWidth="445.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"  fx:controller="source.ControlPanel" >
    <children >

        <TextField fx:id="loginPanel" alignment="BOTTOM_LEFT" text="source.Login" />
        <PasswordField fx:id="passField" alignment="BOTTOM_LEFT"  />

        <Button fx:id="button" text="Logowanie"  onAction="#handle"/>
    </children>

</FlowPane>
```

Second Fxml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
    <?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
    <?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
    <?import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane?>
    <?import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField?>
    <?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
    <FlowPane prefHeight="334.0" prefWidth="445.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="source.ControlPanel" >
        <children >

            <Label text="Second Window"/>
        </children>

    </FlowPane>
```

and can you tell me, can I add 2 onAction in one button ? If i can, tell me how. 
    I forget..

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\bin\java" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.3.4\lib\idea_rt.jar=60332:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.3.4\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Users\kubci\IdeaProjects\FinallyProject\out\production\FinallyProject;C:\Users\kubci\IdeaProjects\FinallyProject\mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar" source.LoginPanel
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8413)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:394)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$353(GlassViewEventHandler.java:432)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:431)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set.
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2434)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2409)
    at source.ControlPanel.handle(ControlPanel.java:51)
    ... 58 more
```

Comment: https://github.com/sedj601/SimpleLoginFx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Opening multiple windows with JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25496692/opening-multiple-windows-with-javafx)

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the line `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set.`, which is related to

```
 FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("source/menuPane.fxml"));
 Parent root1 = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load();
```

Most likely the resource `source/menuPane.fxml` is not in the path relative to the class. If you would do a `System.out.println(getClass().getResource("source/menuPane.fxml"))` my guess is that you get `null`. Given that your path starts with  `source` I'm led to believe that you are under the impression that the runtime will have access to the source.

Make sure that the FXML resource is available in the runtime classpath, make sure that the path you specify is correct according to the runtime classpath.

Answer (score 0):

When i change this :

```
FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/source/menuPane.fxml"));
```

on this:

```
FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/source/stackPanel.fxml"));
```

I get the same window so it works on stack panel .. but i dont know why when i write menuPane program doesnt work. I have good path /source/menuPane.fxml this is in the same package.

Answer (score 0):

I get this now.

```
maj 16, 2018 10:37:44 PM source.ControlPanel open1
SEVERE: null
javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/Users/kubci/IdeaProjects/FinallyProject/out/production/FinallyProject/source/menuPane.fxml
```